# Filtering objects by date

Tags: python, django

My app has an optional date selection. All objects created on that day will be filtered by the selected date.

I have a model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = = models.CharField()
    ...
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Objects will be added every day and there will be a lot of them in the future. I planned to implement filtering with something like this:

```
object = MyModel.objects.filter(pub_date__year=year pub_date__month=month, pub_date__day=day)
```

But it occurred to me that if I make a separate model for the date, link it to the main model and filter by related_name, then the query will be more optimal and faster.

```
class PubDateModel(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = = models.CharField()
    ...
    pub_date = models.ForeignKey(PubDateModel, related_name='my_models')
```

If I understand correctly, then my request will look like this:

```
pub_date = get_object_or_404(PubDateModel, pub_date=date)
objects = pub_date.my_models.all()
```

Which option will be faster with a very large number of objects in the database?